# Masking the file input CSS and javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm able to mask the file input with the following code.

```
<div class="new_Btn" >Choose from computer</div>
<input type="file" name="pic" id="html_btn" style="display:none;" />
```

Then I use javascript

```
 $('.new_Btn').bind("click" , function () {
            $('#html_btn').click();
        });
```

I would like to change the button when the user chooses a file, like print "Image Added" or a tick image.

How would I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('.new_Btn').bind("click" , function () {
            $('#html_btn').click();
            $('.new_Btn').text('Image Added');
        });
```

Comment: You'll have to include more functionality I believe to do exactly what you want. But that's a start.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that's what i was looking for.